# Prioritization within WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Currently I have several endpoints within a single service which invoke the same action but have different throttling configurations based on their priority.

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PriorityService1">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="3" maxConcurrentSessions="3"
        maxConcurrentInstances="3" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="PriorityService2">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="5" maxConcurrentSessions="5"
        maxConcurrentInstances="5" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="PriorityService3">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentSessions="10"
        maxConcurrentInstances="10" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Each of these deals with the incoming SOAP request in exactly the same way (it just throttles them based on priority).  Each of the priorities just inherits from a `BaseService` class like so.

```
public class Priority1Service : BaseService { }

public class Priority2Service : BaseService  { }

public class Priority3Service : BaseService  { }
```

As you can see, there is no implementation in the Priority classes because I just use the inherited behavior.  Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way I can pass the prioritization in the soap message and have the service deal with it based off that? I'd ideally like to be able to get rid of these classes which only inherit behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining different service configurations at the web.config file;

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PriorityService1" name="Sample.Sample">
        ...
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PriorityService2" name="Sample.Sample">
        ...
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PriorityService3" name="Sample.Sample">
        ...
      </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I think that's part of the problem, I already have different services defined.

Comment: then why are you trying to create classes inheriting BaseService?

Comment: Because the functionality remains the same, only the throttling changes dependent on priority.

Comment: AFAIK throttling is configured from the web.config file. So why creating different classes?